# What's differences between ItemView and View in marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

> Version 2.x had many different kinds of views: View, ItemView,
>   LayoutView, CollectionView, CompositeView.
>
> In version 3 ItemView, and LayoutView were ‘merged’ into View, and
>   CompositeView was deprecated for removal in v4. Now we have only View
>   and CollectionView.

What's differences between ItemView and View in marionette 2 ?

If I replace all my ItemView to View in my code in Marionette 3 ? How will I get problems ?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is confusing you? Doesn't marionette has documentation for View and what's itemView? Apart from your quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's differences between ItemView and View in marionette 2 ?

Ok, in older version Marionette we created chosen instance view by use specific class name. 
So. if you want create **itemView** you should use **ItemView** class, or if you want **layout view** instance you use **LayoutView class**. Each view class inherits from basic **View** class, so each views have common attributes, but not all.
**Therefore ItemView is is a special case of View. In M2 create view's instance isn't recommended using direct by View class**

In Marionette 3 you Don't  have to indicate specific class because **View class** 
is a more detailed. Depending on defined attributes your view can be a itemView or layoutView

```
var view = new Marionette.View({ template: "#some-template"});

//So we can say that is a normal itemView
```

```
var layoutView = new Marionette.View({ 
  template: "#some-template",
  regions: {
    menu: "#menu",
    content: "#content"
  });

//So we can say that now is a layoutView, because we defined a regions.
```

**Of course CollectionView has own class as in the previous version.**

> If I replace all my ItemView to View in my code in Marionette 3 ? How will I get problems ?

No, in this case you shouldn't have any problems.